# What Visual Basic syntax is this (Begin/End, no class)?

Tags: syntax, identification

I was recently given some old source code from my employer and asked to determine if it was salvageable enough to port to newer technology or if we should just start from scratch. From what I can tell it is a Visual Basic, Universal Windows project written in Visual Studio. My experience is primarily in C#, .Net MVC/Core/Entity Framework, so I can usually decipher Visual Basic pretty well, but much of the project consists of syntax that I cannot seem to find any information on.

As shown below, the .frm files that make up most of the project contain "Begin VB.Form [FormName]", which contains some attributes and components and is closed by End. After that there are some attributes and subroutines. Nothing appears to be wrapped in a class (as I would expect coming from C#) and Visual Studio is throwing errors everywhere (mostly "Statement cannot appear outside of a method body").

My only guess is that the class is somehow referenced in the Object at the top of the file and everything following extends that, but many of the .frm files do not have an Object at all and Visual Studio complains either way.

So what am I missing here? Do I just have the project type wrong, preventing Visual Studio from properly interpreting it? Is this some old Visual Basic syntax that I cannot find any info on? Is it another language entirely? Or perhaps it is super standard and I just have no idea what I'm doing?

Thanks for the help!

```
VERSION 5.00
Object = "{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0"; "Mscomctl.ocx"
Begin VB.Form frmEqualizer 
   BorderStyle     =   1  'Fixed Single
   Caption         =   "equalizer settings..."
   ClientHeight    =   4200
   ClientLeft      =   -15
   ClientTop       =   375
   ClientWidth     =   7125
   ControlBox      =   0   'False
   LinkTopic       =   "Form1"
   MaxButton       =   0   'False
   MinButton       =   0   'False
   ScaleHeight     =   4200
   ScaleWidth      =   7125
   StartUpPosition =   2  'CenterScreen
   Begin VB.CommandButton CommandCancel 
      Cancel          =   -1  'True
      Caption         =   "Cancel"
      Height          =   315
      Left            =   4080
      TabIndex        =   23
      Top             =   3600
      Width           =   1275
   End
   Begin VB.CommandButton CommandOK 
      Caption         =   "OK"
      Height          =   315
      Left            =   5640
      TabIndex        =   22
      Top             =   3600
      Width           =   1275
   End
   Begin VB.ComboBox ComboPresets 
      Height          =   315
      Left            =   2295
      Style           =   2  'Dropdown List
      TabIndex        =   0
      Top             =   2940
      Width           =   2535
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider80Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   217
      TabIndex        =   1
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider310Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   1552
      TabIndex        =   2
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider1000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   2902
      TabIndex        =   3
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider3000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   3562
      TabIndex        =   4
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider6000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   4237
      TabIndex        =   5
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider600Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   2227
      TabIndex        =   6
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider170Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   892
      TabIndex        =   7
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider14000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   5602
      TabIndex        =   8
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider16000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   6262
      TabIndex        =   9
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider12000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   4927
      TabIndex        =   10
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label2 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "80 Hz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   217
      TabIndex        =   21
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label6 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "310 Hz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   1552
      TabIndex        =   20
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label8 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "1 Khz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   2902
      TabIndex        =   19
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label9 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "3 Khz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   3562
      TabIndex        =   18
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label10 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "6 Khz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   4237
      TabIndex        =   17
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label7 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "600 Hz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   2197
      TabIndex        =   16
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label5 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "170 Hz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   877
      TabIndex        =   15
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label11 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "12 Khz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   4897
      TabIndex        =   14
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label13 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "16 Khz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   6262
      TabIndex        =   13
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label14 
      Alignment       =   2  'Center
      Caption         =   "14 Khz"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   5602
      TabIndex        =   12
      Top             =   240
      Width           =   645
   End
   Begin VB.Label Label12 
      Caption         =   "Apply WinAmp (TM) presets"
      Height          =   255
      Left            =   2295
      TabIndex        =   11
      Top             =   2640
      Width           =   2415
   End
End
Attribute VB_Name = "frmEqualizer"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Public m_nUserResponse As VbMsgBoxResult

Private Sub ResetEqualizerBands()
    Dim nBands As Integer
    nBands = frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandGetCount()
    For i = 0 To nBands - 1
        Dim fFrequency As Single
        fFrequency = frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandGetFrequency(i)
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain fFrequency, 0
    Next i

    Slider80Hz.Value = 0
    Slider170Hz.Value = 0
    Slider310Hz.Value = 0
    Slider600Hz.Value = 0
    Slider1000Hz.Value = 0
    Slider3000Hz.Value = 0
    Slider6000Hz.Value = 0
    Slider12000Hz.Value = 0
    Slider14000Hz.Value = 0
    Slider16000Hz.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateBandsValues()
    Dim fBandwidth As Single
    Dim fGain As Single

    Dim nBands As Integer
    nBands = frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandGetCount()
    For i = 0 To nBands - 1
        ' get settings for the specific band, we are interested in knowing the actual "gain"
        Dim fFrequency As Single
        fFrequency = frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandGetFrequency(i)
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandGetParams fFrequency, fBandwidth, fGain

        Select Case fFrequency
        Case 80
            Slider80Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 170
            Slider170Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 310
            Slider310Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 600
            Slider600Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 1000
            Slider1000Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 3000
            Slider3000Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 6000
            Slider6000Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 12000
            Slider12000Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 14000
            Slider14000Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        Case 16000
            ' this band is available only for sounds with a sample rate equal or higher to 48000 Hz
            Slider16000Hz.Value = -(fGain * 100)
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub ComboPresets_Change()

    If ComboPresets.ListIndex = 0 Then
        ' reset equalizer values and exit
        ResetEqualizerBands
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' load preset keeping in mind that the first element is 'None' so we have to decrease the value
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerLoadPresets ComboPresets.ListIndex - 1

    ' update the gain for each band
    UpdateBandsValues
End Sub

Private Sub ComboPresets_Click()
    ComboPresets_Change
End Sub

Private Sub CommandCancel_Click()
    m_nUserResponse = vbCancel

    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandOK_Click()
    m_nUserResponse = vbOK

    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ' fill the combo box with the available presets
    ComboPresets.AddItem "None"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Classical"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Club"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Dance"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Full Bass"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Full Bass Treble"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Full Treble"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Laptop Speakers"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Large Hall"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Live"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Party"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Pop"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Reggae"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Rock"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Ska"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Soft"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Soft Rock"
    ComboPresets.AddItem "Techno"

    ComboPresets.ListIndex = 0

    Slider6000Hz.Visible = True
    Slider12000Hz.Visible = True
    Slider14000Hz.Visible = True
    Slider16000Hz.Visible = True

    ' hide sliders not useful for certain sample rates
    Dim nSampleRate As Long
    nSampleRate = frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.GetFrequency()
    If nSampleRate <= 11025 Then
        Slider6000Hz.Visible = False
        Slider12000Hz.Visible = False
        Slider14000Hz.Visible = False
        Slider16000Hz.Visible = False
    ElseIf nSampleRate <= 22050 Then
        Slider12000Hz.Visible = False
        Slider14000Hz.Visible = False
        Slider16000Hz.Visible = False
    ElseIf nSampleRate <= 44100 Then
        Slider16000Hz.Visible = False
    End If

    ' check if equalizer bands have already been created
    Dim nBands As Integer
    nBands = frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandGetCount()
    If nBands = 0 Then
        ' create equalizer bands inside the control
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 80, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 170, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 310, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 600, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 1000, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 3000, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 6000, 12, 0
        ' these band are available only for sounds with a sample rate starting from 44100 Hz
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 12000, 12, 0
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 14000, 12, 0
        ' this band is available only for sounds with a sample rate starting from 48000 Hz
        frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandAdd 16000, 12, 0
    Else
        ' update the gain for each band
        UpdateBandsValues
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Slider80Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider80Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider80Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 80, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider80Hz_Scroll()
    Slider80Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider170Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider170Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider170Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 170, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider170Hz_Scroll()
    Slider170Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider310Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider310Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider310Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 310, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider310Hz_Scroll()
    Slider310Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider600Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider600Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider600Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 600, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider600Hz_Scroll()
    Slider600Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider1000Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider1000Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider1000Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 1000, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider1000Hz_Scroll()
    Slider1000Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider3000Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider3000Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider3000Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 3000, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider3000Hz_Scroll()
    Slider3000Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider6000Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider6000Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider6000Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 6000, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider6000Hz_Scroll()
    Slider6000Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider12000Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider12000Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider12000Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 12000, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider12000Hz_Scroll()
    Slider12000Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider14000Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider14000Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider14000Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 14000, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider14000Hz_Scroll()
    Slider14000Hz_Change
End Sub

Private Sub Slider16000Hz_Change()
    Dim fGain As Single
    fGain = -(Slider16000Hz.Value / 100)
    Slider16000Hz.Text = fGain
    frmStart.ActiveSoundEditor1.Effects.EqualizerBandSetGain 16000, fGain
End Sub

Private Sub Slider16000Hz_Scroll()
    Slider16000Hz_Change
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like VB6 code, so you will need the VB6 IDE to work with it.

Comment: That _is_ VB6 code. All *.frm are forms designed with the visual designer. Everything between the `Begin VB.Form` and last `End` is the layout and properties of the form and the controls on it. The actual (user) code starts at the line `Public m_nUserResponse As VbMsgBoxResult`.

If you can, grab an old copy of VS.NET 2008. It has an integrated VB6 -> VB.NET migration wizard. I guess that should make it easier for you to at least browse the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VB6 (and VBA) source code files contain more data than what the VBIDE visibly shows. Attributes, for one, are illegal in the VBE's code panes.

If you imported that file into the VBE, you would see that the in-editor module content begins here (that line should probably be saying `Option Explicit` BTW):

```
Public m_nUserResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
```

Everything above that is designer metadata. Coming from C#, you should be familiar with how WinForms was originally a similar mess (`#region` notwithstanding), until `partial` classes became supported.

The `Begin VB.Form` block can be thought of as some kind of `frmEqualizer.designer.vb` partial class; the code file *itself* **is** a class definition, as indicated by these attributes:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "frmEqualizer"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

If you're translating this code or migrating it to .NET/WinForms, then the `Begin VB.Form` block is your layout metadata, telling VB what controls to load where on the form, and what their designer properties are:

```
   Begin MSComctlLib.Slider Slider14000Hz 
      Height          =   1995
      Left            =   5602
      TabIndex        =   8
      TabStop         =   0   'False
      Top             =   420
      Width           =   645
      _ExtentX        =   1138
      _ExtentY        =   3519
      _Version        =   393216
      Orientation     =   1
      Min             =   -1500
      Max             =   1500
      TickStyle       =   2
      TickFrequency   =   150
   End
```

For example this block defines a `MSComctlLib.Slider` design-time instance named `Slider14000Hz` that slides from -1500 to 1500, 645 twips wide and 1995 twips tall, located at (top:420, left:5602) in form coordinates (twips from upper-left corner).

This line:

> ```
> Object = "{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.1#0"; "Mscomctl.ocx"
> ```

Is loading a COM object registered with CLSID `{831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}`, version 2.1, library "Mscomctl.ocx" - aka *Microsoft Common Controls*, the 32-bit library that defines the `Slider` control in use here (if it's VBA code, it only runs in a 32-bit Office host).

If the form had binary metadata (e.g. embedded icons or images), there should be a `.frx` file in the same folder as the `.frm`, with the same name.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! That helped clear up a lot! And thanks for including the bit about the Object and .frx files (which I didn't even mention). I was wondering about those.